# How to get proper graph in Grafana

Tags: postgresql, grafana

I am using postgresql database with grafana. I have shared the snapshot of graph that i am getting, its very difficult to understand. Please let me know how to get proper graph which is easy to understand.
[image]

Comment: That really depends on the use case and metrics. You didn't provide any details, but it looks like you have 3 dimensions: X/Z axis and time. 3 dimensions in 2 dimension graph - that doesn't look very good.

Comment: I have changed the snapshot of graph, now you can see the query as well. The graph is so spiky, It doesn't look like a time series graph. Please help me to get proper graph and i have just selected a single x-axis parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried query like this and it worked for me, just needed to add the order by

Select ts as time,
key AS metric, 
long_v as value
FROM public.ts_kv
WHERE key = 'PressureZ'
order by time

inorder to get graph in proper format we need to add order by.